# A general inequality about $\mathbb{R}^n$ metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was revisiting Terence Tao's Analysis II. And noticed the inequality

$$(1.1)\,\,d_{l^2}(x,y)\leq d_{l^1}(x,y)$$

So my questions are

1. Is $d_{l^{n+1}}(x,y)\leq d_{l^n}(x,y)$ true?
2. If so then how do you prove it?
3. Similarly, if not then how is that proven?

Comment: Not sure if what you asked even makes sense. There's an inequality which states: if p < q, then: the l-p norm of any sequence > l-q norm of that sequence

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor what part didn't make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $1\leq p\leq q\leq\infty$, we have
$$d_{l^q}(x,y)\leq d_{l^p}(x,y)\tag{$\star$}$$
and therefore your claim $d_{l^{n+1}}(x,y)\leq d_{l^n}(x,y)$ is true.

**Proof:** For any $x\in l^p(\mathbb R^n)$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum_i|x_i|^q&=\sum_i|x_i|^{q-p}|x_i|^p\\
&\leq\sup_i|x_i|^{q-p}\sum_i|x_i|^p\\
&=(\sup_i|x_i|^p)^{\frac{q-p}p}\sum_i|x_i|^p\\
&\leq\left(\sum_i|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{q-p}p}\sum_i|x_i|^p\\
&=\left(\sum_i|x_i|^p\right)^\frac qp.
\end{align}
Then it follows
$$\left(\sum_i|x_i|^q\right)^\frac1q\leq\left(\sum_i|x_i|^p\right)^\frac1p.$$
Replacing $x_i$ with $x_i-y_i$, we easily obtain ($\star$).